# Sending an file via email through Parse cloud module Sendgird

Tags: javascript, email, parse-platform, sendgrid

I am trying to send a file through email using Parse.com 's JS cloud cloud, utilizing Sendgrid. The file exists, it queries it right, it just doesn't attach it to the email

```
var theFile = object.get("file")
var sendgrid = require("sendgrid");
sendgrid.initialize("***", "**");
var email = sendgrid.Email({to: ['pat.doyle95@gmail.com']});
email.setFrom('guy@email.com');
email.setSubject('Payroll');
email.setText("This is the payroll file for yesterday \n \n" + theFile.url())
console.log(theFile)
email.addFile(theFile.name(), theFile).then(function(e) {
    console.log("In file add");
    console.log(e);
    console.log("this is filename " + theFile.name());
});
sendgrid.sendEmail(email);
```

The file exists, and it shows in the email that I receive as well. Although I can still get the file through the URL, I want to attach it in the email.

Comment: Seems like your `addFile` method is with the wrong signature. See the [docs](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs#addfile); it takes a single object, not a list of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The params to addFile are incorrect, try this:

```
email.addFile({
  filename: theFile.name(),
  url: theFile.url()
});
```

Comment: I've been going off of the parse documentation here. https://github.com/elbuo8/sendgrid-parse  I tried that approach but it doesn't recognize the url parameter in parse.com

Comment: Result: TypeError: Cannot call method 'url' of undefined
    at Email.addFile (sendgrid.js:222:40)
    at e.query.find.success (main.js:19:15)
    at e.<anonymous> (Parse.js:14:28224)
    at e.s (Parse.js:14:27156)
    at e.n.value (Parse.js:14:26575)
    at e.s (Parse.js:14:27284)
    at e.n.value (Parse.js:14:26575)
    at e.s (Parse.js:14:27284)
    at e.n.value (Parse.js:14:26575)
    at e.<anonymous> (Parse.js:14:27228)

Answer (score 0):

So nobody else has to go through this huge hassle. The addFile() function is called synchronously and calls addFileFromBuffer() which means that if you send the email right after you add the file then the email will send before the attachment has been created. Call sendEmail() inside the function of addFile().

```
var theFile = object.get("file")
var sendgrid = require("sendgrid");
sendgrid.initialize("***", "**");
var email = sendgrid.Email({to: ['pat.doyle95@gmail.com']});
email.setFrom('guy@email.com');
email.setSubject('Payroll');
email.setText("This is the payroll file for yesterday \n \n" + theFile.url())
console.log(theFile)
email.addFile(theFile.name(), theFile).then(function(e) {
    console.log("In file add");
    console.log(e);
    console.log("this is filename " + theFile.name());
    sendgrid.sendEmail(email);
});
```